# DAG scheduling broke after the time change (29/10/2022) and hasnt worked since

Tags: python, airflow, scheduler, scheduling

I am running a couple of DAGs via airflow which used to run fine until the 29th of October, when the time changed and ever since then they haven't run at all.

The DAGs are scheduled to run every Monday at 6am and below is the code:

```
default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': dt.datetime(year=2022, month=10, day=17),#, hour=10),
        'concurrency': 1,
        'retries': 5,
        'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(seconds=10)

}
bucket_name = "store_order_forecast_s1_2_3"
dag = DAG(
    dag_id=bucket_name,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 6 * * 1',
    catchup=False
)
```

The server is correctly identifying the next run time, but it always skips it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qbCw.png)

Has anyone run in the same issue?

Thank you in advance

I have tried changing the run date and reset the DAG but it didnt work.

Comment: What Airflow version are you using?

Comment: Version: 2.2.5+composer

Answer (score 0):

Has anything else changed in your DAG code around that time? DAGs should be scheduled on UTC so I would not expect the change between summer and wintertime to have an influence on the DAG schedule itself.

Your `concurrency` setting being 1 could be the issue. This means only one task instance can ever be active across all task instances of this DAG: maybe a task got stuck in a running state last October and this is preventing new tasks to be scheduled? I would check in your Airflow UI -> Browse -> Task Instances if old task instances of that DAG are still running (or try setting the concurrency parameter to a higher value, the default value is 16).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The DAG code has changed, but I can run it manually just fine so it's not getting an error. The issue is the DAG never getting kick started to begin with.

I checked in the task instances tab, but there is no instance running for this particular DAG. I could increase the concurrency, but since I don't see a running instance in there, I guess it wouldn't change much. Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Hmm... could you add the scheduler logs to your question? In OS Airflow they should be at `$AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler` (I am not familiar with CC but I think they should be with the `Streaming logs`).